# How to add custom forms in Joomla 3.4 Articles and save data

Tags: php, database, forms, joomla, joomla3.0

I am new in Joomla, I need to add form(inquiry, feedback,...) in pages (it may be articles or ...),

What Should I have to do.There is no predefined feature in Joomla or I have to do copy paste code etc.

Comment: Try to search at google.There are lots of component and module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use components such as [Breezing Forms](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/breezingforms-lite) or [RS Forms Pro](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/rsform-pro).

These components allow you to create custom forms with various features, drop downs, radio buttons, captcha etc.

They also allow you to create modules from based on forms, so you could create the form, **publish** it to a module and then **insert** this module into any article using the `{loadposition}` and `{loadmodule}` feature within Joomla. More information on this can be found [here](https://www.ostraining.com/blog/joomla/loadposition-loadmodule/).

Rather than try to code yourself and hack core files I'd recommend one of these components. There are others that may do the same job however I have personally used these ones and can recommend them.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, its working :)      love to code but component is good..